# Late 1800s, arrogant or bombastic to use ten-dollar words?

Tags: history

TL:DR. In 2020, I don't think anyone uses these bombastic words in a town newspaper! If you write or speak them, I think you look arrogant and pretentious! But did newspaper readers in late 1800s react the same? Did they find these ten-dollar words arrogant and pretentious?

### Detail

In [Jan 11 1870](https://archive.org/stream/dailycolonist18700111uvic/18700111#mode/1up) for [*British Colonist*](http://www.britishcolonist.ca/dateList.php?year=1870)  "Ayers's Cathartic Pills"  ad uses ten dollar Latinate words like "purgative", "viscera", "derangements" You can't find these in ads in 2020!

[image]

[*Regina Morning Leader*
March 19, 1915, p.1](https://library.usask.ca/sni/stories/pol14.html) uses "**anent**" instead "about".

> What the Government proposes is in a sense a war measure, and if we are to make effective the business sense of the province which, we believe, is that in this time of war less than any time can the province stand the drain of the traffic, then the plan of a plebiscite is impracticable. The taking of a plebiscite will now have to wait until after the war, and the Government and Legislature will have to take the onus of whatever action is deemed advisable during the period of the war. To take a referendum before acting will mean too much delay.
>
> The Government's proposals **anent [my emphasis]** this liquor question put in brief and concrete form are the following:
>
> 1. To at once issue proclamation cutting the hours of retail liquor sale to 7 o'clock in the evening beginning 1st April.
>
> 2. To convene the Legislative Assembly as early as possible in the month of May and submit to the House a measure of which the outstanding features will be the abolition of all bar and club licenses from 1st July, 1915, until the ending of the war, and the taking over by the Government of the wholesale liquor business throughout the province immediately.

Comment: You should know that the term __five-cent word__ originated with the telegraph and was used literally in the late 19th century.

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of your earlier question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/528523/what-linguistic-traits-make-english-in-late-1800s-sound-more-formal-scholarly